# How to fill the whole area while using safe area in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to fill the whole area while using safe area in flutter?

As you can see below I'm using safe area to wrap my yellow container.
[image]

My requirement is that I want that yellow colour to fill the area below the status bar (the white space).

Here is the code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Column(
```

I tried to wrap safe area in a column, But that doesn't work!

Comment: Remove the safe area

Comment: No. I want the safe area. Cause as the device changes, some of the contents may go underneath. I don't want to add backgroundColor to scaffold either, because the yellow colour will be visible on the bottom area of safe area.

Comment: You can not change status bar color on ios platform respect to apple policies. You can wrap your safe area and may use an Appbar to change status bar color. otherwise you can not achieve this.

Comment: I don't want to change colour of status bar. Instead I want the yellow colour to fill that area.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `SafeArea()` inside the container:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is changing system overlay color :

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.yellow));
```